# Moq: How to call method on a object with Mock.Of<>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

In the below statements, I'm wanting to set the `Navigation` object's `IsNew` flag to `false` and then also, return `false` to a method `IsCurrentStepUnlocked` invoked on that object

However, on line 4 when i retrieve the value of `IsNew`, it is 'true'

I don't seem to get both, set the value on the object and also setup something to return a predetermined value.

```
1. var mockStatementInformation = Mock.Of<IStatementInformation>();
2. mockStatementInformation.Navigation = new Navigation { IsNew = false };
3. Mock.Get(mockStatementInformation).Setup(x => x.Navigation.IsCurrentStepUnlocked()).Returns(false);

4. var isNew = mockStatementInformation.Navigation.IsNew;
```

Navigation, is defined simply as shown below.

```
public class Navigation
{        
    public Navigation()
    {
       IsNew = true;
    }

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
}
```

How do i set a nested property or call methods on it using Moq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Moq Quickstart - linq-to-mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks)

And assuming this example

```
public interface IStatementInformation {

    Navigation Navigation { get; set; }
}

public class Navigation {

    public Navigation() {
        IsNew = true;
    }

    public virtual bool IsNew { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsCurrentStepUnlocked() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Where both method and property return true by default.

When tested like this results are as expected

```
var mockStatementInformation = Mock.Of<IStatementInformation>(m =>
    m.Navigation == new Navigation { IsNew = false } &&
    m.Navigation.IsCurrentStepUnlocked() == false
);

Assert.IsFalse(mockStatementInformation.Navigation.IsCurrentStepUnlocked());
Assert.IsFalse(mockStatementInformation.Navigation.IsNew);
```

Comment: this still returns true for IsNew, I added a statement below your code like this var isNew = mockStatementInformation.Navigation.IsNew; to verify.

Comment: replace lines 1 - 3 with what is in the above answer. I tested it and it returns `false`

Comment: Ok, it appears that IsNew property must be made virtual, once, I added virtual the result is as expected. Thank you